# ECS What is causing 503 temporarily available?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

Our webserver shows `503 service temporary unavailable` sproadically

It gets back to normal after short period.

Because ECS restarts, I don't get to see the logs, how do I go about debugging this?

Comment: you can check the logs in the cloudwatch. it should tell you something

Answer (score 0):

ECS logs are stored in Cloudwatch. But most probably the cause is the failing health checks of services. You can check the health check status in the target group.